# ConEmu: Open multiple Git Bash tabs on different locations

Tags: split, tabs, startup, git-bash, conemu

I need to setup startup tasks in order to have 3 git bash tabs opened on startup, each in different location.

To open various tabs on various places I used

```
cmd -new_console:s /k "%ConEmuBaseDir%\CmdInit.cmd"  & d: & cd \Projects\Project1

cmd -new_console:s /k "%ConEmuBaseDir%\CmdInit.cmd"  & d: & cd \Projects\Project2

cmd -new_console:s /k "%ConEmuBaseDir%\CmdInit.cmd"  & d: & cd \Projects\Project3
```

There is already a predefined task for Git bash

```
{Bash::Git bash}
"%ConEmuDrive%\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe" --command=usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i
```

So i tried following solutions

```
cmd -new_console:s /k "%ConEmuBaseDir%\CmdInit.cmd"  & d: & cd \Projects\Project1 {Bash::Git bash}
```

and

```
{Bash::Git bash} -new_console:s /k "%ConEmuBaseDir%\CmdInit.cmd"  & d: & cd \Projects\Project1
```

but none of them work.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 7):

Feels sad when an inexperienced user doesn't get a proper help from the author... Oh well. Simple solution is:

Open Settings.

Go to Startup > Tasks.

Click on the plus to add new predefined task.

Name it Git bash::Project1.

Fill in following command

```
-new_console:s:d:D:\Projects\Project1"%ConEmuDrive%\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe" --command=usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i
```

Repeat this step for all desired project.
Add one new predefined task. Call it My.
Fill in following

```
{Git bash::Project1}

{Git bash::Project2}

{Git bash::Project3}
```

Click on Startup.

Select Specified named task and select {My}.

Restart.

Voila.

Answer (score 0):

Awful...

First of all, [ConEmu docs](https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html#syntax) tells that you may use simple `-new_console:d:"d:\Projects\Project"` to set startup directory.

You can't "execute" the `{Bash::Git bash}` from `cmd.exe`, what you try to do using `/k` switch. The `{Bash::Git bash}` is [ConEmu Task](https://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html) and only ConEmu knows how to "run" it.

You last try `{Bash::Git bash} /k "%ConEmuBaseDir%\CmdInit.cmd"` is absolutely wrong. The Bash does not ever know how to execute `*.cmd` files. And `bash.exe` does not support the `/k` switch.

At last, your bash version may set specific directory via bash profile. Possible workarounds are described in [docs](https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinStartDir.html).

BTW, instead of `d: & cd \Projects\Project3` it's more handy and descriptive to call `cd /d d:\Projects\Project3`.