# How to open multiple ConEmu/CygWin Bash terminals at different directories

Tags: bash, cygwin, conemu

I have a Windows environment set up using ConEmu and CygWin64 and I frequently have to open up four different Windows directories and run a script there to launch a server.

In total I have these four things running in order to have a local version of our environment operating.

Like so;

```
C:\code\project1\private-api
C:\code\project2\public-api
C:\code\project2\management-agent
C:\code\project3\back-office
```

So far I have just been manually opening new ConEmu/CygWin Bash tabs and navigating via command line to each directory I need then running the scripts. This is tedious though and I figure there must be a way to have ConEmu launch multiple CygWin Bash tabs in different, specific directories (and maybe even run a script in each directory) but I am at a loss as to how to accomplish this.

I considered trying to do this via a Windows batch script too but I couldn't figure out how to launch ConEmu/CygWin bash windows from a batch file. I'm thinking it's not possible.

I have followed the documentation for ConEmu Tasks but the docs for Task parameters and commands are still confusing me. I tried following the answer in this question as well with little success;

[ConEmu: Open multiple Git Bash tabs on different locations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42514138/8171359)

Anyway, here is how I have my current ConEmu CygWin Bash task set up, which works great when opening single tabs in my home directory (had to provide a link, I keep getting errors when trying to upload an image here);

[ConEmu CygWin Bash Task config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtmQ0.jpg)

Name

```
Bash::CygWin bash
```

Task parameters

```
None
```

Commands

```
set CHERE_INVOKING=1 & %ConEmuDrive%\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe --
login -i -new_console:C:"%ConEmuDrive%\cygwin64\Cygwin.ico"
```

Is it actually possible with a ConEmu/CygWin64/CygWin Bash set up to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Tasks](http://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html) allow to run as many tabs/panes as you wish.
- [Docs](http://conemu.github.io/en/StartupDir.html) explain how to run your shell in specific directory.
- [Ways](http://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinStartCmd.html) to execute some command in bash shell on startup.

Example for two tabs with directories

```
set CHERE_INVOKING=1 & %ConEmuDrive%\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe -l -i -new_console:d:"C:\code\project1\private-api" -new_console:C:"%ConEmuDrive%\cygwin64\Cygwin.ico"

set CHERE_INVOKING=1 & %ConEmuDrive%\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe -l -i -new_console:d:"C:\code\project2\public-api" -new_console:C:"%ConEmuDrive%\cygwin64\Cygwin.ico"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about ConEmu, but you should be able to run a shell script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
mintty --dir /c/code/project1 --exec ./task1 &
mintty --dir /c/code/project2 --exec ./task2 &
...
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
mintty --exec /c/code/project1/task1 &
mintty --exec /c/code/project2/task2 &
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add `C:\tools\cygwin\bin` path to your environment path.

In order to start `cygwin` session in the **Conemu** execute `cygwin -new_console` if you want to have admin privilages exucute `cygwin -new_console:a`.